# having issue with connecting to selenoid/ggr hub

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenoid

I am using selenoid+ggr as selenium grid setup. I am facing an issue while executing tests

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://<username:passwd>@<ggr ip>:4444/wd/hub/session/e6dd37a28e4a50e95985961ee98828050f2e282a52c75b975c2770a85be20e51/url. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
  ----> System.Net.WebException : An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
  ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

While I do the health check, things seems to be ok

when I execute  the test, on ggr ui/selenoid ui I can see the browser is invoked and navigates to my test url  but on the first step after the waiting period is expired I see this error.

Comment: This is probably a firewall restriction on port 4444.

Comment: @vania-pooh how to start the execution again. I did try on different port 4500 , there also I got the same error

Comment: Add firewall rule.

Comment: How to add firewall rule for selenoid